# How to read the json config file inside angular module?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, gruntjs, typescript

I am writing the javascript, AngularJS app using typescript. Also I am using grunt for building. In fact I have started off with [ng boilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp).

Now suppose I have a `config.json` file something like below-

```
{
    "app": "abc",
    "login": "xyz" 
}
```

I want some variables in my app to be configurable. So at some place I could use something like -

```
var loginUrl : string = "def?pqr="+config.app;
```

Now how can I read this config in my javascript files? I am looking for best practice answer. I am fine with substitution at `grunt build` step also.

Note: The config file is present on client itself, i.e no need to load it from server separately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case, I use grunt to inject a config file (shared with the server) in an angular constant module :

Using [grunt-preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess) :

I having a config.tpl.js with :

```
angular.module('app.config', [])

.constant('appConfig', {

    // clientside specific constants
    var1                        : 'value1',
    var2                        : [1,2,3],
    sharedVars                  : /* @echo SHARED_VARS */
});
```

Then, in my gruntFile :

```
preprocess: {
    options: {
        context: {
            SHARED_VARS: grunt.file.read('config.json'),
        }
    },
    config: {
        src: 'src/config.tpl.js',
        dest: 'src/config.js' // true file generated and loaded in index.html
    }
},
```

That way you can inject a full config file in an angular constant module, or pick only the vars you want.

Comment: I did not require sharedVars, so I just used client side specific constants. This means I did not have to use & install grunt-preprocess

Comment: Nice, this solution works as expected. Nevertheless I got an error with 'sharedVars                  : /* @echo SHARED_VARS */'. It's pretty obvious because it's a comment. Do you know if there is a way to avoid the detection of the error ?

Comment: @C0ZEN the file containing the echo is just a template file, you're not supposed to use it as is. It's the generated file src/config.js that you should use.

Comment: @Cétia I don't use it, but my IDE inspect it anyway and tell me that something is wrong. Plus the error when running grunt task.

Comment: @C0ZEN Ha ok, I'm sure you can tell your IDE and linters to ignore tpl files ;)

Answer (score 5):

For client side code you should just use `$http.get` to get the json file from the server. Assuming the json file is http accessible at `/manage/config.json` you would do:

```
$http.get('/manage/config.json').then((res)=>{
     var config = res.data;
});
```

$http automatically does json parsing for you.

Comment: The config file is present on client itself. I will clarify this in question.

Answer (score 4):

here is what i did

```
   var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
   var $http = initInjector.get('$http');
   var configModule = angular.module('portalConfig', []);
   $http.get('../config/Settings.json').then(
            function (response) {

                configModule.value('config', response.data);
            }
        );
```

and then suppose your app module is foo then

```
angular.module('foo',['portalConfig'])
```